# Different JavaScript behavior in WebBrowser with Doctype

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 project, where I show some data in a `WebBrowser` component.

The `WebBworser` in Windows Phone 8 does not show a scrollbar, so I implement one on my own. To do this, I need t know the total height of the document (I use `document.body.scrollHeight` to get it) and the height of the currently shown windows (I use `document.body.clientHeight` to get it). The complete HTML template is

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
      <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width"/>
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {{
                window.external.notify("scrollHeight=" + document.body.scrollHeight.toString());
                window.external.notify("clientHeight=" + document.body.clientHeight.toString());
                window.onscroll = onScroll;
            }}

            function onScroll(e) {{
                var scrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;
                window.external.notify("scrollTop=" + scrollPosition.toString());
            }}

            window.onload = initialize;
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            {0}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        {1}
    </body>
</html>
```

So far so good, my solution works fine. The problem is, I want to use CSS3 so I had to add `<!DOCTYPE>` before the `<html>` tag to make it work.

But adding `<!DOCTYPE>` completely changed the JavaScript behavior, `document.body.scrollHeight` now does not return the height of the whole document, just a number slightly higher than `document.body.scrollHeight`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix such strange issues in Trident you need to get the heights of the document, and not the body.

`document.documentElement.scrollHeight`
Is for the complete height of the document

`document.documentElement.clientHeight`
Is for the height of the currently visible part of the document

*PS. be sure to not store the scrollHeight and clientHeight as they can change due to doc inserts or delayed content loading and/or device rotation*

Comment: What about `document.body.scrollTop`? This always returns 0 now.

Comment: nevermind, `document.documentElement.scrollTop` seems to work